# What part of speech is "only" in "Fame lights a fuse that leads only to extinguishment"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

My impulse is that it's modifying the verb *leads*, and is thus an adverb; yet it seems that a case could also be made that it's exerting power on the phrase *to extinguishment*, a noun, which would make it ... what, exactly? an adjective? I'm confused.

> Fame lights a fuse that leads only to extinguishment.

Comment: Do the test. Try replacing it with an adjective, then an adverb. "A fuse that leads beautiful to extinguishment" — nope. "A fuse that leads beautifully to extinguishment" — aye.

Comment: I like it! Though "beautiful to extinguishment" has something poetic about it, the case is clear, grammatically--thanks for the tip...!

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Yes, that works, but where *beautifully* modifies *leads, only* modifies *to extinguishment.*

Comment: Omitting the quotation marks in the title leads to a very compelling question!

Answer (score 9):

In that sentence, *only* is an adverb, but *to extinguishment* isn't a noun. It's a prepositional phrase. It's quite common for adverbs to modify prepositions (e.g., *completely under the bed*). It's also quite common for adverbs to modify entire noun phrases, (e.g., *even a Möbius strip*, *only the lonely*). They rarely modify individual nouns inside noun phrases, though they [do occasionally](http://www.euppublishing.com/doi/abs/10.3366/E1750124510000486).

Comment: A correction: Adverbs don't modify prepositions, they modify prepositional phrases. Still +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence could also be written like this:

> Fame lights a fuse that does not lead anywhere, except to extinguishment

But it is longer and maybe not as poetic sounding.

In the original wording, "only" emphasizes that there is *nowhere* else for fame to lead. Omitting "only" changes the meaning and with it, the sentence could be interpreted as

> Fame lights a fuse that will likely lead to extinguishment, but there is some chance that it won't.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. That alternative is interesting and seems to emphasize even more the extinguishment; however, it sacrifices, as you note, a poetic sensibility and a certain economy. I'm glad to have confirmed my reading of the sentence with "only" as well; that it's not superfluous, but adds a certain constraint.

Answer (score 1):

'Only' is an adverb modifying the verb by answering the question "leads *where*?" by narrowing the scope of where it may lead.  'To extinguishment' is a prepositional phrase also acting as an adverb modifying the verb by also answering the question "leads *where*?"

This adverb and adverbial phrase work together in harmony to bring about a more complex modification of the verb answering the same question "leads where?" than either of them could have accomplished alone.